# программное вращение vector drawable

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Использую `SurfaceView`, рисую на `Canvas` в отдельном потоке. Необходимо получить из ресурса `VectorDrawable`, задать поворот и нарисовать на `Canvas`, потом изменить угол поворота и снова нарисовать на `Canvas`.
Ресурс получаю, но методов для вращения у `VectorDravable` нет.
Пробовал привести к `RotateDrawable`:

```
RotateDrawable rd = (RotateDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow);
```

Приложение падает. Как быть?

Answer (score 2):

Можно вращать не изображение, а канвас, с помощью метода [`.rotate(угол_в_градусах)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate(float)):

```
canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);  // сохраняем состояние канваса, чтобы в конце восстановить его
canvas.rotate(-angle);
drawable.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

Вероятно, также потребуется задать центр вращения, вызвав [`.translate(delta_x, delta_y)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate(float,%20float))

---

Для обычных `Bitmap` также можно использовать [перегрузку метода `drawBitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint)), которая принимает матрицу преобразования:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(угол, x_координата_центра_вращения, y_координата_центра_вращения);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
```

Comment: немного не обычно вращать канву, но это работает.. спасибо